# uploading a video file with curl request in php

Tags: php, api, curl

Hi i'm facing curl requests for my first time and i'm having problem with a particular one.

I want to upload a video to spreaker site by php request. I have no problem with authentication or text areas, but everything i try i can't upload the media_file. Here's the code:

```
$authorization = "O_AUTH_CODE";

$url = 'https://api.spreaker.com/v2/shows/n_show/episodes';

$test=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($test, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: multipart/form-data' , $authorization));
curl_setopt($test, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($test, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
   'title'=>'MyTitle',
   'media_file'=>'@file_path',
 ));
curl_exec($test);
curl_close($test);
```

and the result is this:

```
{"response":{"error":{"messages":["media_file: Required."],"code":400}}}
```

The request that the api documentation ask is this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH-TOKEN" -F media_file=@audio.mp3 -F "title=Daily News" https://api.spreaker.com/v2/shows/1/episodes
```

The only thing i can notice is that the media file is not passed by string, but i can't figure out how i can do. Some help?

Comment: `@filename` is cURL syntax to read the file content from the file by that name. https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ exists, that will give you code that uses this syntax. If that does not work for you, then replace that part with something that uses the CURLFile class - https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php has examples.

Comment: It works with the CURLFile class thank you very much.